# Dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 8.1, freeze on installation

Tags: dual-boot

I see there are several questions with the same topic as this one. However, I can't manage to solve my problem after all.

I am trying to install a dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04 on my pre-installed laptop (ThinkPad W541) with Windows 8.1. The Windows installation does not have UEFI, I checked for that since many troubleshooting answers recommend me to deactivate UEFI.

This laptop does not contain a CD-ROM, so I've created a bootable USB stick using UUI from http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button and the iso for 14.04 found at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

I've tried two approaches for installing Ubuntu:

1. Using the USB stick
2. Using WUBI from the Windows desktop

This happen when I try using the USB stick. My computer successfully recognize it, and I hit "Install Linux Ubuntu" when the boot screen is loaded. Then my computer works as hell, making a lot of fan noise, but the screen goes black and nothing appears on the screen. I also tried installing Ubuntu through the "live view" from the USB boot, but then the installation freezes at the beginning of the process.

Using WUBI works from the Windows desktop, but when I restart my computer to start the Ubuntu installation it freezes on "Verifying installation configurations..." (both keyboard and mouse freezes as well). And it hangs there for several hours, and I need to force shut down my computer.

I feel like I've tried every tutorial made on this topic, and I am getting quite annoyed about this. I work as a software developer and I really would love to use Linux as a dual boot rather than through slow Virtualbox. Can anyone help me? Is using another distro of Linux more helpful than Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

Installed dual-boot of Ubuntu 12.04 successfully through WUBI. And upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 through Update Manager.